# Access struct elements via index

Tags: c

```
#define GET_STRUCT_ITEM(child, parent, index) ((child*) &(&parent)[0])[index]

typedef struct {
    uint8_t val;
} key_child;

typedef struct {
    key_child key_0;
    key_child key_1;
    key_child key_2;
    key_child key_3;
} key_parent;

key_parent keys = {
    .key_0.val = 11,
    .key_1.val = 22,
    .key_2.val = 33,
    .key_3.val = 44
};

key_child key_a, key_b, key_c, key_d;

int main(void) {
    key_a = GET_STRUCT_ITEM(key_child, keys, 0);
    key_b = GET_STRUCT_ITEM(key_child, keys, 1);
    key_c = GET_STRUCT_ITEM(key_child, keys, 2);
    key_d = GET_STRUCT_ITEM(key_child, keys, 3);
}
```

After some hours of research, I could solve a problem to access any child of a struct with an index, but I think I am not doing it the correct way.

As far I understand what I have done, I select via pointer the first byte of the parent struct, cast it to the child struct and there I select the child index.

Is there a simpler, better, cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use an array if you want to access it like an array?

Comment: Instead of giving the members of `key_parent` numbered names, it would make a lot more sense to simply use an array.  Then you could use legitimate indexing rather than trying to create your own indices into the structure.

Comment: At first i used it like you suggested `key_child keys[6]`, but because of the readability in the debuger i swaped to name the struct values. There is also the posibility i change the names from `key_0` to `enter_up`. `settings_down` or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, I think you made a retrograde move when you changed from an array to the named items.  All else apart, it makes moving things between elements hell compared to using an array.

If you think you must do the named version, then use an anonymous union (and an anonymous struct) from C11 inside your structure:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t val;
} key_child;

typedef struct
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            key_child key_0;
            key_child key_1;
            key_child key_2;
            key_child key_3;
        };
        key_child key[4];
    };
} key_parent;

key_parent keys =
{
    .key_0.val = 11,
    .key_1.val = 22,
    .key_2.val = 33,
    .key_3.val = 44
};

key_parent quays =
{
    .key =
    {
        [0] = { .val = 11 },
        [1] = { .val = 22 },
        [2] = { .val = 33 },
        [3] = { .val = 44 },
    }
};

// Global to avoid 'unused variable' warnings
key_child key_a, key_b, key_c, key_d;
key_child quay_e, quay_f, quay_g, quay_h;

int main(void)
{
    key_a = keys.key[0];
    key_b = keys.key[1];
    key_c = keys.key[2];
    key_d = keys.key[3];

    quay_e = quays.key_0;
    quay_f = quays.key_1;
    quay_g = quays.key_2;
    quay_h = quays.key_3;
}
```

This compiles cleanly with GCC 7.2.0 (compiling on a Mac running macOS High Sierra 10.13) using the command (source file `au97.c`):

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -c au97.c
$
```

Note that you can access the structure either way.  If you don't have anonymous unions and structures available (C99 or earlier), then you have to name the union (`u` is a traditional name for this) and the structure, and use:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t val;
} key_child;

typedef struct
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            key_child key_0;
            key_child key_1;
            key_child key_2;
            key_child key_3;
        } s;
        key_child key[4];
    } u;
} key_parent;

key_parent keys = { .u.key = { { 11 }, { 22 }, { 33 }, { 44 } } };
key_parent quays = { .u.s = { { 11 }, { 22 }, { 33 }, { 44 }, } };

// Global to avoid 'unused variable' warnings
key_child key_a, key_b, key_c, key_d;
key_child quay_e, quay_f, quay_g, quay_h;

int main(void)
{
    key_a = keys.u.key[0];
    key_b = keys.u.key[1];
    key_c = keys.u.key[2];
    key_d = keys.u.key[3];

    quay_e = quays.u.s.key_0;
    quay_f = quays.u.s.key_1;
    quay_g = quays.u.s.key_2;
    quay_h = quays.u.s.key_3;
}
```

This was saved in `au83.c` and compiles cleanly using:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -c au83.c
$
```

With both compilations, I omitted the `-Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes` flags that I normally use because there are no functions other than main in the example code.

Comment: Thx for the detailed answer!